# default gateway after network card damage

Tags: networking, windows-10, ipconfig

This is my default gateway

[image]

I am trying to set up Static IP for windows server 2016 in Virtual box,Author of this tutorial says..his default gateway is `192.168.1.1`..Upon some research,it lead me to believe all default gateways can be either `192.168.0.1` or `192.168.1.1`

But mine is not the same..Only issue i can think of is my network card is damaged,so i can't use WIFI any more unless  i am hardwired..

So my ask is

1.What might be the reason for my default gateway starting with `13.*` and is this my default gateway..

**context for the ask:**
This default gateway is needed for me to assign a static ip for a windows server 2016 host on a virtual box

Below is entire output of `ipconfig/all'`

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-05
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e92f:253b:a61c:ee2b%5(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 940179495
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-3B-56-08-34-17-EB-71-A7-72
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 34-DE-1A-30-06-3D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 34-DE-1A-30-06-3E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 34-17-EB-71-A7-72
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::95d8:be4c:c7f:33c3%17(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.137.70.222(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, January 19, 2018 10:31:54 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, January 20, 2018 10:43:32 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.137.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.137.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 154408939
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-3B-56-08-34-17-EB-71-A7-72
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 202.53.8.23
                                       123.176.37.36
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 36-DE-1A-30-06-3D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5d48:ed1b:a219:efc%30(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.14.252(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 456580634
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-3B-56-08-34-17-EB-71-A7-72
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . :   2001:0:9d38:90d7:45c:ebc3:48ac:3f3b(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::45c:ebc3:48ac:3f3b%22(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234881024
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-3B-56-08-34-17-EB-71-A7-72
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Upon some research,it lead me to believe all default gateways can be either 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1

No. That's just the most popular setup in home routers.

#### The prefix

Traditionally, home networks use the first /24 network out of the "private" 192.168.0.0/16 address range. (Or as it used to be called several decades ago, the first class-C network.) Depending on how you count, "first" is either 192.168.0.0/24 or 192.168.1.0/24.

But it doesn't have to be. If you wanted, you could use **any** address range for your LAN – not necessarily within the 192.168./16 range, not necessarily within *any* private range, and not necessarily the size of /24.

In particular, the 10.0.0.0/8 range (10.x.x.x) is *also* reserved for private use, and is a very common choice when setting up a large network consisting of several dozen subnets.

(Using a public range is also normal – as long as that range actually belongs to you.)

So your computer currently happens to be connected to the `10.137.0.0/16` subnet.

#### The suffix

There is absolutely no restriction as to what IP address can be used as a gateway, as long as it actually belongs to a routing-capable device on the same link (and normally on the same subnet) as you.

But by convention, the first – or last – address within a network is chosen for the gateway, simply because it's more tidy that way. So you commonly see 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.254 as gateways.

And since you are on a 10.137.0.0/16 network, it is reasonable that its first address, 10.137.0.1, will be used for the gateway.

*(The last address would be 10.137.255.254, in case you're wondering.)*

Comment: Thank you this was very clear `There is absolutely no restriction as to what IP address can be used as a gateway, as long as it actually belongs to a routing-capable device on the same link (and normally on the same subnet) as you.`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like dhcp is NOT enabled on your virtual adapter.

1. Take a known good laptop or computer, plug it into your VLAN in question if applicable. Just lan port if no vlans.
2. try to get an autoconfig ip. Check the default gateway ip. Then try to ping it.

You can try to ping 127.0.0.1 from the virtual machine to make sure the tcp/ip stack is working properly.

Your default gateway should always be in the same network subnet as your server/pc.
If the nic is on "192.168.56.x" your default gateway(router) should be something like 192.168.56.1

Post back with more info on your setup and I can help you further.

Comment: Thanks,i believe tcpip stack is working properly,reason being,if I change obtain ip address automatically internet on virtual machine works

Comment: I will try on rest and update the question

Comment: _"If the nic is on "192.168.56.x" your default gateway(router) should be something like 192.168.56.1"_ – yes, that's true for the virtual machines, but the ifconfig output is from the host. It's normal that the virtual adapter on the host will be statically configured, since the host _itself_ is the gateway for those VMs.